# puppeteer browser.new_page is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm running into a problem splitting a working solution using puppeteer into multiple modules for better readability and maintainability... reduced the code down to a few lines demonstrating the issue:

working version:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();        
        await page.goto('https://google.com')
        await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

but as soon as I try to move the puppeteer initialization out of the main function like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function f1() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.new_page();
    await page.goto('https://google.com')
    await browser.close();
}

(async function main() {
    try {
        await f1();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: browser.new_page is not a function
```

Comment: You probably need to write `browser.newPage` not `browser.new_page`

Comment: ouch - this is what happens when you stare at code late at night. I was sure I copy/pasted these few lines but apparently the source I copied from was already wrong. Thanks so much for a fresh pair of eyes !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a typo, it should probably be `browser.newPage` not `browser.new_page`.